# Creating something like a "Virtual Aperture" with speakers, particulary for directional bass

Tags: speakers, waves

I'm asking as I can't find the key things to google for this. I've got an issue where I want to make the bass more directional, and I understand one way is to put the speakers a certain distance apart effectively creating a different shaped aperture for the sound wave (assuming the speakers are in phase).

I.e. if I put my subs together is that effectively one source with an aperture the distance (albeit small) between the cones? And if so, at what distance does the "widening" effect of the aperture on directionality cease in terms of the wavelength, and if anyone has any references on this that would be ideal.

Comment: You may find this edifying: http://www.fohonline.com/current-issue/74-tech-feature/8711-subwoofer-arrays-in-the-real-world.html You can also search for "subwoofer array" to find more info.

Comment: Also this: http://www.prosoundweb.com/article/tech_talk_building_directional_subwoofer_arrays/